# MySQL's different quote marks

Tags: mysql, quotes

I am a bit new to MySQL and just wanted to know what is the difference between:

```
`   '    "
```

when I'm using them in a query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ` you write mysql variable names.
With ' you write mysql variable values

For example

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `x` = '1'
```

Answer (score 7):

I would add that the way double quotes are interpreted depend of wether or not your `MySQL` server has [ANSI quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) turned on or off.

In the former you cannot use double quotes as a string delimiter.

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE last_name = "norris" ;
```

will return you a punch in your teeth.

Comment: The link is broken. A version-agnostic way seems to work. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Answer (score 2):

``quotes you dont need to escape where as string quotes you do ''single or ""double

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

use ` (backquotes) for column name

use ' or " for values

Don't use backticks with column values. use either single or double quotes otherwise mysql  considered that value as a column name.