# What's the difference between ` ' and " in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have seen different ways on how to use it but I don't understand the why...

say a simple SQL..

```
$q = "UPDATE table SET
col1 = '$var1',
col2 = '$var2'
 ";
```

So that is one way...

```
$q = "UPDATE table SET
`col1` = $var1,
`col2` = $var2
 ";
```

This does the same, but why the use of `?

and then:

```
$q = "UPDATE table SET
'col1' = $var1,
'col2' = $var2
 ";
```

So what is the correct way to use it, when to use it, and why...
then I have seen this:

```
$q = "UPDATE table SET
col1 = ".$var1.",
col2 = ".$var2";
```

Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Add the `mysql` tag in your question, if your question is about MySQL.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642644/mysqls-different-quote-marks

Answer (score 0):

The backtick `` ` `` is for reserved words or column names, while a normal single quote `'` is to encapsulate strings.

You can read the detailed info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Edit: As pointed out, this is for MySQL only. Different database engines use different methods to encapsulate tables, solumns or reserved words.

Comment: In MySQL, MSSQL uses [] and Postgres ""

Answer (score 0):

what happens when your column is called `"date"`  ?  Mysql will not know if you have used a function wrong or if you meant a column called `date`

It should be used often to make mysql aware your using a column and not let it do the guess work.

The second question, there is no difference. But you shouldnt build query's like that, instead look at prepared statements

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php